# Split models into multiple files Python import package/subpackage

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I am receiving the following error:

```
Error: ImportError: No module named models.account
```

I am trying to split up my models.

Here is my project structure:

```
site
  | site
  |  | models
  |  |  | __init__.py
  |  |  | account.py
  |  | views
  |     | __init__.py
  |     | site.py
  | __init__.py
  | resources.py
  | routes.py
  | security.py
```

site/site/views/site.py

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound
from site.models.account import User


@view_config(context='pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPForbidden',
         renderer='generic/login.mako')
@view_config(route_name='generic_login', renderer='generic/login.mako')
def login(request):
  if request.scheme == 'http':
    request.scheme = 'https'
    #return HTTPFound(location=request.url)

  if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
    uemail = request.params['email']
    pw = request.params['pass']

    user = User.objects(email=uemail).first()

  return {}
```

Path

```
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/bin
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WebError-0.10.3-py2.7.egg
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.6-py2.7.egg
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Tempita-0.5.1-py2.7.egg
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/site
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WebHelpers-1.3-py2.7.egg
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python27.zip
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Volumes/workspace/py/website/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I'am new to python so trying figure this out.

Comment: The code that triggered the exception doesn't seem to be in your example code.

Comment: where is the actual import statement? also, attaching the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)` would be helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: sorry, it was missing the most important code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`site` is the name of [one of standard Python modules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html), which is, to make matters worse, is a special case and is imported automatically during interpreter initialization. This is likely to be the cause of the problem if the system `site` module overrides yours.

You may try to work around the problem by using something like

```
from ..models.account import User
```

but ultimately it would be worthwhile to rename your project.

Another common problem of confusing import errors in Python is circular module dependencies - say, if you have

```
from site.views import blah
```

somewhere in your `site.models` module, and at the same time trying to do `from site.models.account import User` from `site.views` that would result in a circular dependency which basically manifests in anything below the offending import statement to be not defined. If you have trouble finding a circular import please update your question listing all places where `site.models` and `site.views` are imported.

Comment: I tired renaming the project, and problem still occurs. 

but from ..models.account import User works. Is this my only option? is it possible to do project.models.account import User?

Comment: @slik: it is definitely possible, most larger-than-trivial projects do that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @slik: btw, when trying to rename the project, did you change the import statements as well?

Comment: as of now i am only importing a model in views/site.py. Yes I changed all my imports. The weird part is that I created a new model file, and I can do from site.views.site import login.

Comment: @slik: please review all places where you import site.models and site.views and also all imports _from_ site.models and site.views. My guess would be that you may be importing something from `site.models.account`, and that module in turn imports `site.views`, possibly indirectly